# bind multiple statement to try expression in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I want to do same as below code to my kivy button button in kv file

```
try:
  print"first action"
  print"second action"
except:
  print"there was an error"
```

here is the kv file and button in which I want to do that button I am getting error:

```
on_release: 
  try: \
    print("first action")
    #first action is working but second is not working
    print('second action'):

  except:\
    print("it is not working")
```

it gives me error like:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-06-28_29.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] Video: failed (multisamples=2)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] trying without antialiasing
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <2.1 Mesa 8.0.5>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <VMware, Inc.>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.20>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 128, in <module>
     ExampleApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 797, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 594, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1749, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1796, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1185, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1291, in parse
     rule.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1053, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1051, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 976, in precompile
     self.co_value = compile(value, self.ctx.filename or '<string>', mode)
   File "./example.kv", line 180
     print("second action")
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so is there any solution?to do multiple things after try statment ?

Comment: Based on your traceback, the first snippet of code you gave us isn't what you are using. Could you please post _exactly_ what you are using?

Comment: I just want to run multiple action when i releasebutton like printing two times...but kivy gives me error when i printtwo times....but it allowme to perform only one print statement...

Comment: It is probably due to an error on the previous line. Can you please give us exactly what you have on line 179 in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that kv lang supports exceptions. Move your code to your Python class:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Test>:
    Button:
        text: "..."
        on_press: root.react()
""")

class Test(FloatLayout):
    def react(self):
        try:
            print("first action")
            print("second action")
        except:
            print("there was an error")

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Simply printing several times is easy:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Test>:
    Button:
        text: "..."
        on_press:
            print("first action")
            print("second action")            
""")
```